# How to solve proguard problems when building android apk ？

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

After updating Gradle3.0 and building up APK with Proguard, I get a lot of  warnings like this:

```
Warning :can't find referenced method.....
```

But my `proguard-rules.pro` file works well on Gradle 2.3.3.

I'm bypassing this by adding many `-dontwarn` flags, but in the end remains only one warning：

```
Warning:u.aly.ap: can't find referenced method 'void registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)' in program class android.app.Application
```

How can I suppress this warning?

Comment: Should you read first "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: I'm sorry , my english is very poor.